# $P$ and $Q$ are ideals of ring $R$, $\phi: R \rightarrow R/P \oplus R/Q$, determine $\ker \phi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$P$ and $Q$ are ideals of ring $R$. To determine $\ker\phi$ of $\phi: R \rightarrow R/P \oplus R/Q$, did not understand a step:

$\ker(\phi) = \{x\in R: \phi (x)=(0,0)\} = \{x\in R: (x+P,x+Q)=(0,0)\}=\{x\in R: x\in P\cap Q\}$.

So did not understand the last step. Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Comment: It's just the definition of being $0$ in the quotient ring. $x+P = P = 0+P$ so $x \in P$, and similarly for $Q$.

Comment: When they write $x+P = 0$, they mean the $0$ of the quotient ring $R/P$, which is $P$ or equivalently $0+P$.

Comment: Thanks, occurred to me just now.

Comment: Writing $x+P$ for the coset of $x$ in $R/P$ instead of $[x]$, $\overline x$ or just $x$ but then just writing $0$ instead of $[0]$, $\overline 0$ or $0+P$ is really *bad*!